# Can't use variable from public Form2 in private void?

Tags: c#

```
namespace Bus
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         string selectedItem=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      }

      private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         groupBox1.Text=selectedItem;
      }
   }
}
```

When I run this, I get an error for selectedItem in private void saying that  selectedItem does not exist in the current context.

Why is that? If I declare the string in public Form2(), shouldn't others be able to use it since it's public?

Comment: This is a problem with `scope`. Your variable is declared in the constructor, and trying to be accessed in a method. Declare `selectedItem` globally.

Comment: ah I see. public Form2() is a constructor. Oops. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a number of things you need to consider here

firstly any variable created inside a method can only be used inside that method
because of this you need to upgrade it from a local variable to a class variable

secondly how are are going to upgrade it it can be done in several ways

Field : this is generally used to things that are only needed inside the class not outside (though they can be declared public this is not best practice)
eg

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private string selectedItem;
```

Property : Properties are used when fields need to be used outside the class or when you need addition control over what happens when data is got or set
eg

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string SelectedItem{get;set;}
```

Static : this is when you need to access the variable from every instance of a class not just the one its set in, static can be either a field or property
eg

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public static string SelectedItem{get;set;}
```

which you need is dependent on what you need to accomplish

also just because a class is public doesn't mean everything on it is public,

you might have things on it that are only useful inside the class (private)

only in the class or its descendent (protected)

only inside the project (internal)

or accessible to everything (public)

so you must set the access on each method or property separately (if you don't it will default to internal), properties allow you to set this for both the get and the set separately so you can have a property that anything can read from but only the class itself can change

Answer (score 2):

`selectedItem` is a local string for your `Form2`'s constructor only. You need to either create it as a field or property for all components of your `Form2` class to be able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

define `selectedItem` as property or field:

```
namespace Bus
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public string selectedItem {get; private set}
      //private string selectedItem;

      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         selectedItem=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      }

      private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         groupBox1.Text=selectedItem;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: why does set need to be private?  the set of selecteItem is referring to selectedItem=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() yes?

Comment: @user2521723, it also may be public if you want to change this property outside of Form2 class. if you don't need to read it outside it will be better to use private field

Answer (score 1):

Well, `selectedItem` is a *local variable* and can be used  *locally* only,  within the *constructor* scope in your case. Convert it into *property*:

```
namespace Bus
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public String SelectedItem {
        get {
          if (null == listBox1.SelectedItem)
            return "";

          return listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() 
        }
      } 

      private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         groupBox1.Text = SelectedItem;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it a class level field

```
namespace Bus
{
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      private string  selectedItem;

      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         selectedItem=listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      }

      private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         groupBox1.Text=selectedItem;
      }
   }
}
```